# $5$ dots on a $8$x$8$ board

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We randomly distribute $5$ dots on a $8$x$8$ board, such that no square contains more than $1$ dot (excuse me for the spelling, i'm not sure if 'square' is the right word. Hope you know what i meant - square means one of the $8^2$ cells in the board).

What is the probability that there's no row, or column, which contains more than $1$ dot?

The solution was $\frac{280}{5673}$.

My (incorrect) attemp is:

$\frac{{8 \choose 5}*{8 \choose 5}}{64 \choose 5}=\frac{7}{17019}$

$|\Omega|={64 \choose 5}$. The first ${8 \choose 5}$ is for choosing the $5$ rows i want to place my dots and the seconde ${8 \choose 5}$ is for choosing the rows i want them to be.

What's wrong with my solution?

Comment: $|\Omega|={64\choose 5}/5!$, since the dots are indistinguishable

Comment: Your denominator counts ordered pairs. Your numerator doesn't, because it doesn't actually associate the $x$-coordinates with the $y$-coordinates. (For instance, your numerator doesn't distinguish between selecting $(2, 5)$ and $(3, 4)$ from selecting $(2, 4)$ and $(3, 5)$.) To fix, consider the number of ways to glue the $x$- and $y$-coordinates together to make pairs, which is $5!$.

Comment: oh now i get it! thanks a lot @AaronMontgomery !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To the numerator you need to multiply by $5!$ for the ways to permute the dots in the chosen five rows and columns, since there must be exactly one in each row and column *of the induced submatrix*.